# Resultset returning data in sample single java project but same Resultset returning false in an project

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

In my java code, query result set returns **false** even if that query have data, but same query result set returning data while done in a sample project which contains only one java file.

```
 TranSegmentQry = "SELECT TRAN_ID FROM TRAN_SEGMENT WHERE SEGMENTNAME = '"+segmentName+"'";

//segmentName getting as input ex: PRDSUM_SEG

        stmt = lConnection_NEW.createStatement();

        if(segmentName != null && segmentName.length()>0){


            rs=stmt.executeQuery(TranSegmentQry.toString().trim());


            while (rs.next()){                  
                mLog.debug("Not even entering into this while loop"+lResultSet);
                lresultMap.put("TRAN_ID", lResultSet.getString("TRAN_ID")!=null? lResultSet.getString("TRAN_ID"):"");
                }}
```

Comment: If it returns true in one, and false in the other, then you don't have the data in the database. And please, **do not concatenate values into a query**, use a prepared statement.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Am using the same database for both code and used prepared statement using if loop also but dint't work   ps=lcon.prepareStatement(TranSegmentQry);  
  ps.setString(1, segmentName);
  rs1=ps.executeQuery();
  if(rs1 != null && rs1.next())
  {
   mLog.debug("Data"+rs1.getString(1));
  }

Comment: Obviously you are either not using the same database, or not the same code or values, otherwise you would have received the same result. Software is deterministic. If it doesn't behave the same then it is not the same or the environment is different (or both).

Comment: Different computers? Check that the connection URL, net and user/password fit. (PreparedStatement indeed important.)

Comment: Same Computer but one sample project & one big project, i have used **DatabaseMetaData** to get DB url & username --> both codes returning same connection. Help me out guys @JoopEggen

Comment: Log TranSegmentQry. Use a local variable Statement stmt and close it. Same for rs. Test without WHERE. Debug. I am afraid we cannot really help when no evident errors pop up from the code. The class of lConnection_NEW could be the culprit.

Comment: @JoopEggen thank you

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank You